# Magento2: How to add a new product type

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, custom-product-type

This new product type will contain parent informations of other products. 
These products are only for internal use, so I only need to add attributes and a new type of relation to other products, like Up-Sells, Cross-Sells.
All other default informations like prices, description, etc. are not needed.

What is the best way to create this product type.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Step 1: Generate the `app\code\Vendor\Module\registration.php` file

Setup the `app\code\Vendor\Module\registration.php` file

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Generate the `app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">

    </module>
</config>
```

Next, the creation of the `etc/product_types.xml` file is necessary to determine the model of the new product type.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="new_product_type" label="New Product Type" modelInstance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\NewProductType" indexPriority="60" sortOrder="80" isQty="true">
        <priceModel instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Price" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Enter the code :
>   `Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\NewProductType` model

Enter the code below: `Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\NewProductType` model, that should be based on `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType`.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type;

class NewProductType extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType 
{

}
```

After that, it is possible to rewrite some functions and implement some changes you want there.

> Step 3: `Enter the Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Price` model

Enter `Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Price model`, which should be based on the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price`.

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product;
 class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price
 {

 }
```

Besides, you can also set the new product type as versatile type with some custom functions after extending the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price class`

> Step 4: Public the new Magento 2 Product type

This is the step allowing you to check the result in the Magento 2 Administrator when completing the above steps. The New Product type will display as the old types (Simple or Configurable Product).

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: @christian if it's helpful then please mark my answer correct and upvote my answer so it helps other readers as well. Keep coding 

Comment: I followed your expalnation, but I get an Error when I run the **setup/update** command: **There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.**

Comment: I edited my answer in step 3 price model there is issue in the namespace please again copy and paste the code of step3.

Comment: @christian then please mark my answer correct it helps other readers as well. Keep coding 

Comment: Where can I mark your answer as correct???

Comment: You have to click the tick mark (✓) near to my answer

Comment: Is it possible to remove fields from the field set. I only use this product type to store additional informations for my other products. So I dont need fileds like tax_class, quantity, weight, categories...

Comment: Yes it may be possible if it doesn't hurt the magento default functionality, for this you have to research it through internet