# How to add New Product Type similar like Configurable in Magento2.3?

Tags: magento2.3

I have to make new Product Type similar like Configurable and I have tried the below reference which is working but I cannot add/update Product Price and Qty. Qty all the time becomes Zero, also Configurations is missing similar like Configurable Products.

Reference : [Magento2: How to add a new product type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266023/magento2-how-to-add-a-new-product-type)

Github : https://github.com/Genmato/DemoProduct

How to fix it?

Comment: Why would you need to create a new product type? Are you sure you can't fit your needings just extending some functions of existing product types?

Comment: As per client requirements need to make new product type and need to customize.

Answer (score -1):

> Vendor/Module/etc/product_types.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="custom_product_type_code" label="Custom Product Type Label" modelInstance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type">
    </type>
</config>
```

A product model must inherit from the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType base class.`  **TYPE_CODE** which defines the product type code string, so it can be referenced in code in a consistent manner.

> Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product;

class Type extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    const TYPE_ID = 'custom_product_type_code';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        // method intentionally empty
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Setup

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //associate these attributes with new product type
        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
        ];

        // make these attributes applicable to new product type
        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
                ',',
                $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
            );
            if (!in_array(\Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_ID, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_ID;
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New product types can allow themselves to be children of composite product types by adding a node to the composableTypes node in

> Vendor/Module/etc/product_types.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="custom_product_type_code" label="Custom Product Type Label" modelInstance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type">
    </type>
    <composableTypes>
        <type name="custom_product_type_code" />
    </composableTypes>
</config>
```

In addition to the product type model, a module can specify a price model in the product type definition XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="custom_product_type_code" label="Custom Product Type Label" modelInstance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type">
    <priceModel instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Price" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: It's working in Simple Product not in Configurable Product.